# Do I need to allow space for over provisioning in an Crucial m500 SSD

Tags: ssd

I’m looking at buying a 1TB Crucial M500 SSD to use in my mid 2012 non retina MacBook Pro.

When I format the drive do I need to allow an in partitioned portion as an over provision or will the drives firmware take care of this and only let me use the correct amount of space in the first place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The M500 already has 32 GB of factory set (Level 2) for over-provisioning.

That much over-provisioning was because it was a new NAND architecture and Crucial
wanted to ensure that the drive was stable.

As the device is already keeping 32 GB and allowing you to only touch 480 GB,
to ensure drive reliability, you can use everything that it lets you.

Comment: Thanks , it’s actually a 1TB drive so presumably it will let me use 960gb. If I run the drive near full capacity will I notice a slow down or with the pre set over capacity will it be alright

Comment: I believe that 32 GB should be enough for the firmware to maintain the disk, but nobody has ever come up with any useful numbers for over-provisioning.

Comment: @harrymc Is this 32GB there on Crucial's MX500 SATA SSDs? These are new ones I guess, but their spec doesn't have any mention of it.